# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.os.bhavik.Bhavik.<init>(com.os.dbo.MetaData)

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I have on class named `AbstractAccessManager` which gives me the instance of class with the help of the **Reflection API**.

The Structure of `AbstractAccessManager` is like below:

```
public class AbstractAccessManager{

    public static HashMap<String, String> accessManagerPackageMap;

    static
    {
        fillMap();
    }
    public static HashMap<String, String> fillMap()
    {

        accessManagerPackageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        accessManagerPackageMap.put("Bhavik", "com.os.bhavik.");    

        return accessManagerPackageMap;
    }

    public static AccessManagerHandler getAccessLevel(String accessName,MetaData metaData) throws InvalidAccessException 
    {
        AccessManagerHandler handler = null;
        try {
            String packge=accessManagerPackageMap.get("Bhavik");
            System.out.println("Package Name="+packge);
            Constructor c = Class.forName(packge+accessName).getConstructor(MetaData.class);
            handler = (AccessManagerHandler)c.newInstance(metaData);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.out.println("No such handle found...."+accessName);
            throw new InvalidAccessException();
        }

        System.out.println(handler.getClass().getName());
        logger.info("ClassOFWIKI="+handler.getClass().getName());
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Now i have written the test case which will mock the `getAccessLevel(String s1,MetaData mData)` using **JMockit**. But I get the error that `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.os.bhavik.Bhavik.<init>(com.os.dbo.MetaData)`. How can I solve it? where am I going wrong?

Here is My TestCase using JMockit

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class AbstractAccessManagerTest1
{
   @Mocked
    LogService logService;

    MetaData metaData;

   @Mocked
     Bhavik bvk;

   @Mocked
    Constructor constructor;

HashMap<String, String>map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    HashMap<String, String>map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();

  AbstractAccessManager ab;
    String accessName = "Bhavik";

@Test
    public void testMathod() throws InvalidAccessException,Exception
    {
        ab = new AbstractAccessManager();
        map.put("Bhavik", "com.os.bhavik.");

        map1 =Deencapsulation.invoke(ab, "fillMap");

        String name =Deencapsulation.invoke(map1, "get", accessName);
        assertEquals("com.os.bhavik.", name);

new Expectations()
        {
            {
                Class.forName(name+accessName).getConstructor(MetaData.class);
                returns(constructor);
            }
        };

assertEquals(map,map1);

}
```

Comment: you need to paste full stack trace. Also , Expectations block has to be before actual invocations ( play phase ) , why Expectations in the end of your test method?